# How can i use condition in widget?

Tags: flutter

How can I use condition in widget? I did it with empty widget like `container()` or `Text()` but when I put `empty Widget` in `row()` and give `spaceBetween` of `MainAxisAlignment` it takes their own space without any showing. Searching on the internet I think there are only the old info so that's not working anymore (if I am wrong I'm really sorry).

If conditions are not allowed and I do not want to show the widget - How can i do that?

Comment: Provide more detail also add some code

Comment: Please write a proper and detailed question. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to render Row conditional with size of childrens.

```
List<Widget> elements = []
Row(children: elements)
```

First option is to initiate `elements` inside your `initState(){}` method.
Another one, if you want to change it dynamically, then you have to know about `setState(){}` method and how `key` works, that is optional attribute of all Stateful/Stateless Widgets.

Comment: thank you actually i saw the youtube video about key published by google developer but it's a little bit iffy so... do you now any other site to understand about key?